# Rest controllers for relation entities conventions

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have simple java app with three entities:

```
User
Rent
Tool
```

User can rent multiple tools and tool can be rent by multiple users. The Rent entity is there to track rent history so it has many to one relations with both User and Tool.

At the moment I have two rest controllers:
UserController
ToolController
that are responsible for serving users or tools.

The problem is that now i want to return rent history for specific user. Should I create method in UserController with mapping like

```
/users/{id}/rents
```

or it is better to create separate controller like RentController and method with mapping like

```
/rents?userId={userId}
```

I think that first approach is cleaner in terms of URI, but I have to use the RentService in UserController and because these are classes from different packages (I use package-by-feature approach) I feel that there is something wrong.
The problem is also with methods like POST, or PUT, where I think the best option will be something like this:

```
POST /rents - RentDto as body
PUT /rents/{id} - RentDto as body
```

or maybe it is ok to have method:

```
GET /users/{id}/rents
```

in RentController and not in UserController?
How you solve such problems and what would you suggest?

Comment: I would create RentController, with CRUD methods for rent entity. That way you stick to SOLID principles by keeping classes to single purpose. eg;. if you had to retrieve rents count for tool? Would you add another method to tools controller? That way both user and tool controller would have methods returning rent data, which is not perfect.

Comment: Is the Rent table really holding only the manyToMany relationship between the two entities or it could be extended to contain some additional data as well, like rental specific info? Try to avoid making your UserResource/UserService a monster just because something seems to logically fit there.

Comment: it hold also additional data like date when tool was rent and when user returned it.

Answer (score 3):

When we are talking about RESTful API we should be able to reach any CRUD method without extra parameters, so, considering that, I would use the path parameter approach (`/users/{id}/rents`).

Normally we use query parameters in case that you want to get a list or items of a list with a very specific information.

I recommend [this article](https://medium.com/@fullsour/when-should-you-use-path-variable-and-query-parameter-a346790e8a6d) for more details.

Comment: Ok so the second question is where should I place this method? UserController? Then UserController is responsible not only for User so it can be confusing as @CrazySabbath pointed out. RentController? When someone will search for /api/users/1/rents the first place will be probably UserController, because URI suggests so.

Comment: I guide myself, normally, looking for the correct scope. It is clearly an user information for me and the base path is /users/, so I would put it under UserController because: 1. It is an user particular information; 2. The base path guide us to search on user scope when troubleshooting this service

Answer (score 0):

```
/users/{id}/rents
```

About my opinion, it's more clearly and easy to understand if you use above url and just return the list rents of user.

```
/rents/{id}/user
```

Will help to track this rent is currently used by who.